# Cast a void pointer to another type based on an input parameter

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, declaration

I am trying to create a variable of type A or B based on an input parameter and assign a casted void pointer to it.

```
void set_info_param(void* info, bool req)
{
    ...
    if (req)
        struct info *capa_info = (struct info *) info;
    else
        struct info_old *capa_info = (struct info_old *) info;
    ... [Use capa_info]
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error:

> expected expression before 'struct'

Comment: Please post the full code. for the function (at least a [mre]). We don't know if there are any errors before the if statement.

Comment: An `if` statement must be followed by a `statement`. A `declaration`, which is what you have there, is **not** a `statement`. You can fix it by putting the declaration inside curly braces `{ }`, but that of course defeats what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you define new variables you need to put it into blocks like:

```
if (req)
{
    struct info *capa_info = (struct info *) info;
    ...  // use capa_info
}
else
{
    struct info_old *capa_info = (struct info_old *) info;
    ... // se capa_info
}
// capa_info can not be used here
```

Answer (score 0):

In C declarations are not statements.

On the other hand, the if statement expects a sub-statement.

So if you want that the sub-statement of the if statement had a declaration then enclose the declaration in the compound statement like

```
if (req)
{
    struct info *capa_info = (struct info *) info;
}
else
{
    struct info_old *capa_info = (struct info_old *) info;
... [Use capa_info]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a variable of type A or B

This is not how C types works. Every variable has a type which is known statically at compile time. You cannot have a variable assume one of the two types based on a run-time condition. If you need two different types, you have to use two different variables.